# CSS - Display inline block elements with a border and text-overflow

Tags: css, sass

I have an `inline-block` element that I want to put a `border-bottom` on, but when the text inside that element wraps to the next line, it puts the border on the bottom of both lines of text, instead of just the bottom of the element.

Heres a demo:

http://codepen.io/Tiger0915/pen/azpeVY

And here's the pertinent SCSS:

```
div {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  span {
    border-bottom: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  }
}
```

How do I get it to only put the border on the bottom of the element?

**Reason I have to use `display: inline-block` and can't just use `display: block`:**

- I need text to be able to wrap to a new line, as the screen size is
  small
- I can't specify a defined width on the `span`, it needs to change width based on whether or not the text can fit on 1 or multiple lines (depends on screen width)
- The span needs to be `text-align: center` within the div

Comment: That's not CSS syntax. What is that, less or sass?

Comment: It's SCSS, I'll update that part of the question, thanks.

Comment: In your fiddle you don't use `display: inline-block`. If you use it, it works. [**demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEgojM).

Comment: This is what @Oriol is talking about http://jsfiddle.net/k6sbbf44/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your SCSS to this and it worked fine for me:

```
div {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  span {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  }
}
```

Just add `display: inline-block;` to the span like you said. By default, `<span>` elements are `display: inline;` not `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: 3 mins ago: "I changed" - 9 mins ago: "In your fiddle you don't use display: inline-block. If you use it, it works. demo." ...

Comment: @Cristoph yes we both reached the same conclusion. His was a comment and mine was an answer. Either way, it works and it's much simpler than Michael's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap  the span in a div and assign the `border-bottom` to the div.

add a wrapper div

```
<div>
  <div class='wrap'>
    <span>
      This is a long sentence.
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

assign `border-bottom`is SCSS

```
div {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  width: 150px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 20px;

  text-align: center;

  div {
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    span {

      font-size: 24px;

    }
  }
}
```

Here is a working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwaOoN).